# Multiple actions were found that match the request using POST method .net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Controller looks like the following, the `get` works ok, but when a `post` is called recieve the referenced :

```
[ActionName("import")]
public void PostImport([FromBody]string file = "myString")
{}

[ActionName("something")]
public void PostSomething()
{}

[ActionName("bool")]
public Boolean GetBool()
{}
```

routes register like below :

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
  name: "DefaultApi",
  routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
  defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
  name: "ControllerAndAction",
  routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}"
);
routes.MapRoute(
  name: "Default",
  url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
  defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

The request I am using is this :

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"file":"myOtherString"}' http://localhost:6
1393/api/admin/import
```

Comment: Please had the view code and have you tried adding `[HttpPost]` attribute to the posted method

Comment: @3dd its an api controller there is no view, adding httppost did nothing

Comment: What's the url you are posting to and what data are you including in the post body?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL /api/admin/import matches two different routes.

It matches DefaultApi with a controller of "admin" an id of "import".

It also matches ControllerAndAction with a controller of "admin" and action of "import".

So it can't work out which route to use

Comment: Do you need the DefaultApi route? If not just remove it. If so then you'll need to form your urls a little differently so you can distinguish between the two routes.